# How to get a warning if some code is blocking the main thread in SWT?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I am seeing lots of code in Eclipse that is blocking the main thread by accessing the filesystem or the network, probably because the developer did not get a warning from SWT when developing it.

Is there a way to get a warning if some code is blocking the main thread in SWT?

I would like to see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html for SWT.

Comment: Are you sure the code is actually running in the UI thread. A lot of Eclipse code runs in Jobs or other methods of running in non-UI threads. There isn't any way of ensuring this but core Eclipse code is generally well written and does the correct thing.

Comment: I found a bug in EGit similar to: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335044 I will post it later next week

Comment: I submitted a request for enhancement to: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=510477

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool to statically analyze SWT code and detect code passages that would block the UI thread.

The only way to find code that blocks the UI thread would be to observe the application at runtime.

If you are using the Eclipse workbench/IDE, you can enable the *UI responsiveness monitoring* (*Preferences* > *General* > *UI Responsiveness Monitoring*) to find code that runs on the UI thread for too long.

The SWT events `PreEvent` and `PostEvent` (register listeners at the `Display`) allow you to measure the time that application code takes to process events.

Comment: That will not be able to detect IO on the UI-Thread that may took very little time on the developer machine, but may take a lot of time on a user machine where a network filesystem is slow or the network is slow.

Comment: Right, such cases will go unnoticed.